# How To Configure Atom IDE to Run Elixir Dependencies?

Tags: atom-editor, elixir

I'm getting errors when running Elixir files inside Atom IDE when a dependency is referenced in the script.

I'm using the Atom package "Script" to run the file.

Here's the code:

```
# This Elixir code runs fine when using Atom package "Script"
IO.puts "hello world"
```

### When a dependency is referenced (NimbleCSV in this case) I get the error:

```
IO.puts "hello world"
NimbleCSV.define(MyParser, separator: "\t", escape: "\"")
```

> ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function NimbleCSV.define/2 is undefined (module NimbleCSV is not available)
>       NimbleCSV.define(MyParser, [separator: "\t", escape: "\""])
>       (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:669: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
>       (elixir) lib/code.ex:168: Code.eval_string/3

### When running the same file in Terminal using "mix run [filename]" the file runs without errors.

How do I configure Atom so that is recognizes the Elixir dependencies?

Comment: Looks like it's a missing feature. That package just executes `elixir -r <filename>`: https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/blob/f080c7243d8c50898348c205cb5adb79db8cdcef/lib/grammars.coffee#L222-L228 It should check for the existence of `mix.exs` in any parent folder and run `mix run <filename>` if it finds any.

Comment: Any possible workarounds?  Maybe a way to configure the Script package to execute mix run <filename> instead?

Comment: Try applying these changes to the source of that package: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a6f62f651a5215ed36f197aba8faf89e Note that this will break running Elixir scripts that are _not_ in a mix project. An actual solution would require some more code. I'll see if I can find time to write that today.

Comment: Thanks Dogbert.  The changes worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a different package, take a look at [build](http://atom.io/packages/build). In my *opinion*, it has the advantage of letting you choose a separate package as build provider. So, whenever there are several compilers to choose from, you can install a build provider (if available). As for Elixir, there actually is a [build provider for mix](https://atom.io/packages/build-elixir).